# Windows 10 Download Failed

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade, dell-xps

I am downloading **windows 10** by using **Windows Media Creator**. Currently i am using **Windows 7 Dell XPS** L502X 15R(Early 2011)Laptop. My Download is **stuck at 78%** and my **Panther Log file** detail at that process was :

2015-08-23 05:02:30, Warning               MOUPG  Bits Error: Fatal = [No], State = [TransientError], Error_Context = [BG_ERROR_CONTEXT_REMOTE_FILE], hr = [0x80072EE2], Description = [The operation timed out]

So will the **Download continue** or *have to do it again deleting those files*.

P.S. - I always face this kind of incompleteness upgrading to Windows 10. I tried nearly every possible thing to get the new OS but the error 800702EE2 /800702EFE which is cause due to Windows Server connection with my computer was dropped. If you know other ways to do or Have a FIX Please tell me.

Comment: You can try some direct link to download iso file.